# Apache-spark: Equal column data structure, different outcome in UDF function

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two array of columns

```
arrayColumns1: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = array("col1","col2")
arrayColumns2: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = array("col1","col2")
```

Both seems equals, but they came from different sources.

- `arrayColumns1` is from a conversion of `Array("col1","col2")` to an `array`, using this function:

  ```
  def asLitArray[T](xs: Seq[T]) = array(xs map lit: _*)
  ```
- `arrayColumns2` is from writing the textual Array.

Now when I try to use `arrayColumns1` as input to an UDF function:

```
.withColumn("udfFunction",udfFunction(arrayColumns))
```

where

```
val udfFunction= udf(
  { xs : Seq[Double] => 

    DO_SOMETHING
    (output)
  }
)
```

It thorows me this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(array(col1,col2))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<double> type, however, 'array('col1','col2')' is of array<string> type.;;
```

But when I use `arrayColumns2` it works fine. What did I do wrong?

I'm using Spark 2.1 over scala 2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make much sense to pass an array of literals to an UDF, because what you want to pass is the name of the columns, not literal values. Your second case fails because you are creating columns of type string (`lit("col1")` is a literal column with a content of "col1", it does not reference the column `col1`)

I would to it like this:

```
def asColArray(xs: Seq[String]) = array((xs.map(x => col(x))): _*)

val arrayColumns = asColArray(Array("col1","col2"))

df.withColumn("udfFunction",udfFunction(arrayColumns))
```

If you really want to use literal values, you would need to do something like this:

```
val arrayColumns = asLitArray(Array(1.0,2.0))
```

But this would give you a constant output of your udf